# How to play sound in Choregraphe without a physical robot?

Tags: audio, pepper, choregraphe

I don't have a robot, but I would like to have Pepper say "Hello everyone" in Choregraphe, for example. The speech bubble becomes visible, but no sound is played. How can I make the sound play in Choregraphe?

Comment: It's not feasible as there's no tts in your computer. But theorically it's not impossible: you just need to do your own naoqi module running on your pc, nammed it ALTextToSpeech and generate sound when receiving say command. You can do that in python, I think in a couple of hours. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [make sure the volume of your robot is up](https://support.unitedrobotics.group/en/support/solutions/articles/80000951637-pepper-2-9-how-to-adjust-the-volume).
Then, when you will run your Choregraphe behavior, it's the robot that will be talking, not Choregraphe.

If you are working with a virtual robot however, it does not support producing speech.